# How to optimize this Query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query but is very slow.

```
SELECT
        d.idcartera,
        concat(d.cedula, ':', planilla.fuerza, ':', planilla.cuotas, ':', d.libranza, ':',   planilla.promotor) AS ClienteCedula,
        concat(d.nombres, ':', planilla.fuerza, ':', planilla.cuotas, ':', d.libranza, ':', planilla.promotor) AS ClienteNombre,
        d.valor,
        d.tipo,
        concat(d.ano, '/', d.mes, '-', left(d.tipo,3)) AS anoMes,
        planilla.fuerza,
        planilla.cuotas,
        planilla.promotor
        FROM cartera AS d
       INNER JOIN cartera AS x ON d.cedula = x.cedula
       INNER JOIN cartera AS y ON d.cedula = y.cedula
       INNER JOIN planilla ON d.libranza = planilla.libranza
        WHERE (d.tipo not like '%RI-%') AND (left(x.tipo, 3) like 'RC-') AND (left(y.tipo, 3) like 'RCN')
        GROUP BY d.idcartera, d.cedula
```

Sorry the "y" table is to filter some data

Comment: What do your keys look like?  Are d.cedula, x.cedula, y.cedula indexed?  What about the d.tipo and x.tipo fields, do you have calculated indexes on those fields?

Comment: maybe stating what means slow and what would you like to achieve would help possible repliers. Also, if you already tried some optimisations, it would help to post your trials.

Comment: Nothing obvious from the query itself... the 'like' clauses in the where clause is likely causing a bit of a headache.  one quick reqrite:  (left(x.tipo, 3) like 'RC-') can be  (left(x.tipo, 3) = 'RC-')  (no need for like).   Outside of that, going to need to know your table structure and indexing to help optimize this further.

Answer (score 0):

For the fist part of the query (querying and grouping cartera AS d) you should consider the following index:

```
CREATE index i1a ON cartera(cedula, idcartera, tipo, liberanza);
CREATE index i1b ON cartera(idcartera, cedula, tipo, liberanza);
```

or

```
CREATE index i1c ON cartera(tipo, idcartera, cedula, liberanza);
```

(depending on your DBMS, if the "left/like"-Operation can be applied to the index-column tipo.

for the joins to x and y you should add following index (if it is not already PK):

```
CREATE index i2 ON cantera(cedula) (if you will use i1b or i1c)
```

For the join on planilla, add
    CREATE INDEX i3 ON planilla(liberanza) (if not already PK)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT d.idcartera,
       concat(d.cedula, ':', planilla.fuerza, ':', planilla.cuotas, ':', d.libranza, ':',   planilla.promotor) AS ClienteCedula,
       concat(d.nombres, ':', planilla.fuerza, ':', planilla.cuotas, ':', d.libranza, ':', planilla.promotor) AS ClienteNombre,
      d.valor, d.tipo, concat(d.ano, '/', d.mes, '-', left(d.tipo,3)) AS anoMes,
      planilla.fuerza, planilla.cuotas, planilla.promotor
FROM cartera d INNER JOIN
     cartera x
     ON d.cedula = x.cedula INNER JOIN
     cartera y
     ON d.cedula = y.cedula INNER JOIN
     planilla
     ON d.libranza = planilla.libranza
WHERE (d.tipo not like '%RI-%') AND (left(x.tipo, 3) like 'RC-')
GROUP BY d.idcartera, d.cedula;
```

You are doing a self join three times, not referencing the `y` table, and doing an aggregation with no aggregation functions.

The first simplification is to remove the `y` all together.  I think the join to `x` is needed for filtering, so I'll replace that with an `exists`.  And, I am guessing that the final query doesn't require aggregation with these simplifications.  So, perhaps this does what you want:

```
SELECT d.idcartera,
       concat(d.cedula, ':', p.fuerza, ':', p.cuotas, ':', d.libranza, ':',   p.promotor) AS ClienteCedula,
       concat(d.nombres, ':', p.fuerza, ':', p.cuotas, ':', d.libranza, ':', p.promotor) AS ClienteNombre,
      d.valor, d.tipo, concat(d.ano, '/', d.mes, '-', left(d.tipo,3)) AS anoMes,
      p.fuerza, p.cuotas, p.promotor
FROM cartera d INNER JOIN
     planilla p
     ON d.libranza = p.libranza
WHERE d.tipo not like '%RI-%' AND
      exists (select 1
              from cartera x
              where d.cedula = x.cedula and
                    x.tipo like 'RC-%'
             );
```

You might want to still include `select distinct` if this produces many duplicates.

I am assuming that you have indexes on the `join` key (notably `planilla(libranza)`).  You also want an index on `cartera(cedula, tipo)`.  Unfortunately, the expression `d.tipo not like '%RI-%'` cannot make use of an index because of the initial wildcard.  If you need performance for this, you might want to consider a full-text index on the field.